# Move file to destination if filename contains string

Tags: powershell, move

I have a script that will move files from one place to another if it has a certain file extension.

```
get-childitem -Recurse -path "S:\Vecta\Test\" | where {($_.extension -eq '.old')} | move-item -Destination "S:\Vecta\Archive"
```

Is there a way to modify this script so it looks for .old files with the word "AMA" contained in the filename? And moves the files to the destination path?

I've had a good search but all I can find is scripts that send a file to a destination based on the filename, not if it contains a specific word.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the condition `-like "*AMA*"`

```
get-childitem -Recurse -path "S:\Vecta\Test\" | where {($_.extension -eq '.old' -and $_ -like '*AMA*')} | move-item -Destination "S:\Vecta\Archive"
```

Edit: you could combine the two `where` conditions to have `-like "*AMA*.old"`

Answer (score 2):

Just use this, if its not supposed to be case-sensitive:

```
get-childitem -Recurse -path "S:\Vecta\Test\" -filter '*AMA*.old' | move-item -Destination "S:\Vecta\Archive"
```

Enhanced Version would be:

```
$name = 'ama'
get-childitem -Recurse -path "S:\Vecta\Test\" -filter "*$name*.old" | move-item -Destination "S:\Vecta\Archive"
```